# Alternatives for Burp Suite in Linux

Tags: internet, proxy

As I understand, Burp Suite helps in creating proxy listeners on local address and thus intercept the communication between the browser and the internet. Is there any similar software in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla firefox has a extension which can intercept:

[Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [webscarb](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Webscarab)

> WebScarab is a framework for analysing applications that communicate
>   using the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. It is written in Java, and is thus
>   portable to many platforms. WebScarab has several modes of operation,
>   implemented by a number of plugins. In its most common usage,
>   WebScarab operates as an intercepting proxy, allowing the operator to
>   review and modify requests created by the browser before they are sent
>   to the server, and to review and modify responses returned from the
>   server before they are received by the browser. WebScarab is able to
>   intercept both HTTP and HTTPS communication. The operator can also
>   review the conversations (requests and responses) that have passed
>   through WebScarab